# REVIT API. Can I set geometry from DirectShape for inserted FamilyInstance?

Tags: revit-api

I have project document that has DirectShape element. 
I create new Family with 1 FamilySymbol. FamilySymbol is created without geometry.
Then I loaded new Family and inserted NewFamilyInstance.  And I want to set Geometry, but geometry got from DirectShape.
I can't find way to do it.
Is there way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

A family instance is one Revit database element, represented by a FamilyInstance object. A direct shape is another Revit database element, represented by a DirectShape object. Normally, direct shapes are used to completely avoid the need (and overhead) to define a family and insert a family instance of it. If you insist on using a family instance, you can also create the direct shape element inside the family definition instead of placing it in the project.

Comment: Thanks for  answer. How can i create or post DirectShape element to inside family? I have read RevitApi.  There are few methods for creating shape - extrusion, blend ... and other.

Comment: Global problem in that i import DWG file that has few shapes.  Then project file has new shape Instead of few shapes as it is in DWG file. Then i am geting each block (GeometryObject) from this new shape  and then i am creating  DirectShape.  In result i have few shapes that is not defined. But i need family.

Comment: DirectShape.CreateElement Method (Document, ElementId): http://www.revitapidocs.com/2017/bee8a24f-704e-44d9-e187-9e031548a6d2.htm

Comment: Yes. I know this method. But i will get direct shape that is not defined. I need create family with geometry as DIrectShape when i imported DWG file

Comment: DWG file import is managed differently. I do not believe that DWG can be imported directly into direct shape. Can you achieve that in the user interface? If not, then it is probably not possible programmatically either. If you wish to create a direct shape from a DWG file, you can read and analyse the DWG file contents yourself using the AutoCAD.NET, RealDWG or Forge Design Automation API, understand the geometry, and create the corresponding direct shape yourself using the Revit API.

Comment: I can import DWG and create few DirectShape shapes by API. But i need to create family and move geometry from created DirectShape to new Family